# Keep record of people who open Excel file

Tags: excel, logging, trace, vba

The code below does exactly what I want.. It keeps a record of people that opens my excel file but the problem is that it keeps the file open to everyone.

I want this tab to work in the background, so it is not visible to anyone except for me, when I go to the backend or click a button somewhere that will make it visible.

Please not that just the case the tab Audit is visible, the code must always check if the tab is opened and hide immediately when someone opens the file

Thanks in advance

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" ( _
    ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
    nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" ( _
    ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
    nSize As Long) As Long

Private pAuditSheet As Worksheet
Private Const USERNAME_COL = 1
Private Const COMPUTERNAME_COL = 2
Private Const OPEN_TIME_COL = 3
Private Const CLOSE_TIME_COL = 4
Private Const OPEN_WB_NAME_COL = 5
Private Const CLOSE_WB_NAME_COL = 6
Private Const KEEP_ONLY_LAST_N_ENTRIES = 1

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Workbook_Open
    ' Runs when the workbook is opened.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   Me.Worksheets("Audit").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

   Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RowNum As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim S As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Set WS = Me.Worksheets("Audit")
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Set WS = Me.Worksheets.Add(before:=1)
        WS.Name = "Audit"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With WS
        If .Cells(1, USERNAME_COL).Value = vbNullString Then
            .Cells(1, USERNAME_COL).Value = "User Name"
            .Cells(1, COMPUTERNAME_COL).Value = "Computer Name"
            .Cells(1, OPEN_TIME_COL).Value = "Open Time"
            .Cells(1, CLOSE_TIME_COL).Value = "Close Time"
            .Cells(1, OPEN_WB_NAME_COL).Value = "Open WB Name"
            .Cells(1, CLOSE_WB_NAME_COL).Value = "Close WB Name"
        End If
        '.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        RowNum = .Cells(.Rows.Count, USERNAME_COL).End(xlUp)(2, 1).Row
        N = 255
        S = String(N, vbNullChar)
        N = GetUserName(S, N)
        .Cells(RowNum, USERNAME_COL).Value = TrimToNull(S)
        N = 255
        S = String(N, vbNullChar)
        N = GetComputerName(S, N)
        .Cells(RowNum, COMPUTERNAME_COL).Value = TrimToNull(S)
        .Cells(RowNum, OPEN_TIME_COL).Value = Now
        ' Leave Close Time empty. It will be filled on close.
        .Cells(RowNum, CLOSE_TIME_COL).Value = vbNullString
        .Cells(RowNum, OPEN_WB_NAME_COL).Value = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        ' Leave Close Name empty. It will be filled on close.
        .Cells(RowNum, CLOSE_WB_NAME_COL).Value = vbNullString
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Workbook_BeforeClose
' Runs when the workbook is closed.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RowNum As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim LastDel As Long
    Dim FirstDel As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WS = Worksheets("Audit")
    With WS
        RowNum = .Cells(.Rows.Count, CLOSE_TIME_COL).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(RowNum, CLOSE_TIME_COL).Value = Now
        .Cells(RowNum, CLOSE_WB_NAME_COL).Value = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        If KEEP_ONLY_LAST_N_ENTRIES > 0 Then
            EndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, USERNAME_COL).End(xlUp).Row
            If EndRow > 2 Then
                FirstDel = 2
                LastDel = EndRow - KEEP_ONLY_LAST_N_ENTRIES
                If LastDel > 2 Then
                    .Cells(FirstDel, "A").Resize(LastDel - 1, 1).Select
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Function TrimToNull(S As String) As String
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' TrimToNull
' Returns the portion of string S that is to the
' left of the vbNullChar, Chr(0).
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim N As Long
    N = InStr(1, S, vbNullChar)
    If N = 0 Then
        TrimToNull = S
    Else
        TrimToNull = Left(S, N - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I probably could open your spreadsheet using LibreOffice or Gnumeric without you knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

you may find that if you uncomment the line

```html
.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

it will most probably work in the way you want it to!